# What is the difference between "Ajirna" and "Ajirni"?

Tags: dua, arabic

I don't know Arabic very well.

Our imam in the mosque says "Allahumma Ajirna Minan Naar" and we say "Ameen" to it.

Now due to lockdown,  I hear to radio more often and I noticed that the Imam in the radio says "Allahumma Ajirni Minan Naar "

Is there a difference between the two  ?

I asked my teacher but she was also confused.She said that the latter is the correct one according to her knowledge.

Please explain

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well in that case the imam on the radio is rather selfish.

> اللهم أجرنا من النار.
>   Allahuma ajirna Mina (a)n-Naar

means something like Allah save **us** from the hellfire.
And it is correct to say "ameen " as he includes himself and all those listening to his/this du'a. So this formulation is correct for a person making du'a for himself and others like an imam of jumuah prayer.

While

> اللهم أجرني من النار.
>   Allahuma ajirni Mina (a)n-Naar

means something like Allah save **me** from the hellfire.
And it is only correct to say "ameen" if you whish this for the person doing this supplication (which certainly is a good deed) or if you've repeated the words behind him. And this formulation is correct for a person making du'a for himself.

In both cases the verb أجار/يجير (ajaara/yujeeru) has been used in the imperative form.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification. It was extremely enlightening. May Allah give you the best of Rewards

Comment: Doesn't this mean the Imam became selfish and afraid of his life? @TheMadHatter did you ask the Imam about it?

Comment: @Kabeer it depends on his intention, if he didn't know the difference and doesn't know Arabic it shouldn't be regarded as such.

Comment: @Medi1Saif If he doesn't know the difference how can he change it? Of course I'm not judging. But he has to be asked anyway

Answer (score 0):

Salam

It's just as this brother just said if you say Allahuma ajirna minanar it mean save us all but ajirna means me .

It is better to say ajirna as it's for everyone and If you do dua for other people yours more likely to be accepted like they say when you do dua do it for prophet Mohammed and family then ummah then right at the end yourself cause it will have more chance to being excepted.  Remember me and my family in your duas. JazakAllah Khair.

Answer (score 0):

These two terms viz ajirni and ajirna are alike and means the same. The only difference is of grammar. When we ask for forgiveness for alone or for only one person, we use singular (ajirni); and on the other hand when we pray and ask for forgiveness publically from the hell fire, we use plural (ajirna) which means "save us". I hope you understand. Still if you don't or you have any other questions regarding Islam, feel free to contact me. Regards

Answer (score -1):

Jazaak Allah

- My job is of an imam in a masjid
- Googled this Q
- Ur ans was a source of relief & enlightenment (masha Allah)
- May Allah accept from both of u : Ameen

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE. Please note that this does nothing to answer the asked question (See [ask]).